# fix the 'expected expression, got keyword else ' error JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a code box that lets you enter a correct code and then it will tell you.

```
var code = document.getElementById("codeInsertBox");
   var codeText = code.value;
   if(codeText == "08213"); 
   var newItem = document.createElement("div");
   newItem.innerHTML = messageI;
   document.getElementById("messageAppear").appendChild(newItem);
   localStorage.setItem('call', '10');
   } else {
   alert("Incorrect Code. Please try again. (If you are seeing this message and the  correct code message has appeared, it is an error. Please contact me at myEmail@gmail.com)");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `;` after if which terminates the if there right away and the else became orphan.

When you do `;` the statements ends there right away.

```
   if(codeText == "08213");
```

equals to

```
 if(codeText == "08213"){}
```

Basically your code not inside the if condition. So your equals to

```
if(codeText == "08213"){}
   var newItem = document.createElement("div");
```

Remove that `;` and you'd be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are ending if statement. you need to change your code from

```
if(codeText == "08213");
```

to

```
if(codeText == "08213"){
```

Hope everything will work fine with this.

Answer (score 0):

remove ; in this line.

```
    if(codeText == "08213");
```

and correct format your code like this.

```
    if(codeText == "08213"){
        //
    } else {
       //
    }
```